# How i cannot ignore 0(zero) as a grade?

Tags: c

```
int main(){

    char students_number[30], students_grade[30];
    char *number, *value;
    int flag=0, students, i, grade, a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0, f=0;
    float sum=0;

    while(flag==0) // This while loop exist just because to run program until the number of students will be given correct..
    {

        printf("Please enter the number of students (It must be between 1-100): ");
        scanf("%s",&students_number); //  This scanf gets the number of students as an array instead of integer because the number which was given needs to be checked..
        students = strtol(students_number, &number, 10); // strtol is a function of stdlib.h and checks the variable is whether int or not for this program..

        if(students<=100 && students>0)
        {
            for(i=1;i<=students;i++)
            {
                printf("Please enter %d. student's grade (in integer form):",i);
                scanf("%s",&students_grade);//  This scanf gets the number of students as an array instead of integer because the number which was given needs to be checked..
                grade = strtol(students_grade, &value, 10); // This line checks the grade which was given is integer or not by using strtol which is in the stdlib.h..

                if(grade<0 || grade>100 || grade=='\0') 
                {
                    printf("The grade of the student was given incorrect!\n");
                    i--; // To make the for loop which is on the 25th line work again until the grade will be given correct..   
                }
                else
                {
                    if(grade<=50 && grade>=0) // This if and else if commands work for to count how many f,d,c,b and a are exist..
                        f++;
                    else if(grade<=60 && grade>=51)
                        d++;
                    else if(grade<=73 && grade>=61)
                        c++;
                    else if(grade<=85 && grade>=74)
                        b++;
                    else if(grade<=100 && grade>=86) 
                        a++;
                    sum += grade;               
                }
            }
            sum /= students; // This command divides the sum of the grades to number of the students to get the average results in the class..

            printf("\nThe average result of the class is %.2f..\n",sum);
            printf("\nThe letter form of the all results are:\nNumber of F: %d\nNumber of D: %d\nNumber of C: %d\nNumber of B: %d\nNumber of A: %d\n",f,d,c,b,a);
            flag = 1; // As it was mentioned before, this commands exist to break the while loop because the program was done successfully..
        }
        else // This if command controls the number of students wheter was given right or not..
        {
            printf("Please enter a proper number of students.\n");
            flag = 0;           
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hello, this is my first question. I had to create a program which calculates the average of the results. But when i enter 0(zero) as a grade then it doesn't allow it just because i tried to exclude the every types except int type.

How can i make this correct?

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what your question is?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: if i use this instead of the other if(grade<0 || grade>100) then it will allow the all char type things and it will enter a loop

Comment: I didn't understand your question. `scanf("%s",&students_number);` => `scanf("%s", students_number);`, `scanf("%s",&students_grade);` => `scanf("%s",students_grade);`

Comment: @user3121023 Thank you very much!!  I'm appreciated!

Comment: Why didn't you use `scanf("%d",&grade)` instead of `scanf("%s",&students_grade)`

Comment: @SirJoBlack to ignore the other types except integer

Comment: But the %s modifier is used for strings instead of integers. %d is used for integers.

Comment: @Unh0lys0da Yes that is right but that's already what i want to comb out the other types.

Comment: @user3121023 but if 'qw' is entered in %d then the program return 0 as integer. I need a warning if some type is entered except int. In this case, if it'll warn the user then it will not get 0(zero) as an integer.

Comment: The part `grade=='\0'` is probably what makes you problems. I assume when you enter a `0` you get the "grade ... incorrect" message? Note that `'\0'==0`, so remove that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scanf` to read a number and check that `scanf` done correctly its work:

from [man scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf):

> **Return Value**
>   These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

So you can check that you've read an integer with `scanf`, without writing `if (value == '\0')`, which prevents you to read 0 grades...

```
for(i=1;i<=students;i++)
{
    int ok;

    printf("Please enter %d. student's grade (in integer form):",i);

    /* read line from input. Why using fgets instead of scanf directly? See http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html*/
    if (NULL == fgets(students_grade, sizeof students_grade, stdin))
    {
         perror("fgets");
         exit(1);             
    }

    /* **try** to parse what have been read */
    ok = sscanf(students_grade, "%d", &value);

    /* check that scanf has done its work */
    if (1 != ok)
    {
        printf("The grade of the student was given incorrect!\n");
            i--; // To make the for loop which is on the 25th line work again until the grade will be given correct..   

    }
    else
    {
        if(grade<=50 && grade>=0) // This if and else if commands work for to count how many f,d,c,b and a are exist..
        f++;
        /* ... */
    }
```

I also advice you to read this article: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html.